# Play Service granular dependency error

Tags: android, google-play-services, android-gradle-plugin

I try to use new Granular Dependency for Google Play Service 6.5.+

In my gradle I set:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.3'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:6.5.87'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:6.5.87'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:6.5.87'
}
```

but I get back this error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
Error: more than one library with package name 'com.google.android.gms'
You can temporarily disable this error with android.enforceUniquePackageName=false
However, this is temporary and will be enforced in 1.0
```

I've all SDK updated.

What's the correct way to use this new feature?
Thanks.

**SOLVED**

The problem is that *android-maps-utils* already have the Play Service 6.5.+, so the error.

Comment: answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24795074/error-more-than-one-library-with-package-name-com-google-android-gms

Comment: The conflict seems to be between the android-maps-utils libraries and any of the play-services libraries. I'm not sure if android-maps-utils is no longer needed or if something is mispackaged.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `android-maps-utils` library currently [already includes](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils/blob/ee924f7f074a9a24a87c8427f04778e21f95f5e6/library/build.gradle#L19) the Google Play Services. You can try one of the following:

1. Open an issue on [their issue tracker](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils/issues) so they adapt or help you out (which would mean others would benefit from it too).
2. Try this, I haven't tested this and **it might not work**! I haven't looked into the maps utils to see what they actually use.

   ```
   compile('com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.3') {
       exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms'
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks, your solution partially works, I open a tracker issue.

Comment: Please once you find a working solution, edit your post and include it there so others can profit from it. :)

Comment: Can you please post the link of the issue?

Comment: Sure! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27402145/play-service-granular-dependency-error

Answer (score 5):

This was apparently [fixed](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils/issues/138) in version 0.3.4 of the maps-utils library, but it required that I remove the references to play-services-maps and play-services-location.  I am still able to use play services and location services, so I'm guessing the maps-utils already includes those.
My gradle file then only contains:

```
compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.3.4'
```