# Not enough space for ad banner

Tags: java, android

I try to add an admob banner. It works good on all devices with big screensize, but when I try to run it on device with a small screen resolution, the ad doesn't appear.

In logcat I see:

> I/GMPM﹕ App measurement is starting up
>   E/GMPM﹕ getGoogleAppId failed with status: 10
>   E/GMPM﹕ Uploading is not possible. App measurement disabled

and

> W/GooglePlayServicesUtil﹕ Google Play services out of date.  Requires 8115000 but found 6599034
>   E/GooglePlayServicesUtil﹕ GooglePlayServices not available due to error 2

and

> W/Ads﹕ Not enough space to show ad. Needs 320x50 dp, but only has 288x420 dp.

Here is main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/gradient"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.nesususu.nes.app.onResume">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout20"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="false"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="false"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:gravity="top|center_horizontal"
    android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/timeField2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_gravity="top|center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginBottom="73dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:padding="12dp"
        android:shadowColor="@color/bright_foreground_disabled_material_dark"
        android:shadowDx="0"
        android:shadowDy="0"
        android:shadowRadius="24"
        android:text="00:00:00"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="#06ff00"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        android:textStyle="normal|bold"
        android:theme="@style/Animation.AppCompat.DropDownUp" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="86dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout16"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal">


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnExit"
        android:layout_width="91dp"
        android:layout_height="86dp"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:background="@drawable/btnexitcode"
        android:gravity="center" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout16"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout16"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id"></com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

build app

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'com.nesususu.nes.app'
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 3
        versionName "1.2"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.1.0'
}
```

I tried to move the ad to relative layout, to hardcode the width, but the result is the same.
Devices I tested are Xperia acro S and Samsung Galaxy tab E, both work good.
But some phones like Samsung SM-G360H, won't show the ad. The resolution of last one is 480 x 800, so it should have enough space.

Answer (score 0):

> getGoogleAppId failed with status: 10

I had same error and I resolved him with this:

You should configure your google-services.json file and download [here](https://developers.google.com/mobile/add?platform=android&cntapi=signin&cnturl=https:%2F%2Fdevelopers.google.com%2Fidentity%2Fsign-in%2Fandroid%2Fsign-in%3Fconfigured%3Dtrue&cntlbl=Continue%20Adding%20Sign-In)

For example you can check how to integrate sign-in button [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating).

> W/GooglePlayServicesUtil﹕ Google Play services out of date. Requires 8115000 but found 6599034

You are using play-services:8.1.0 which I think is for sdk version 23. You have targetSdkVersion 22. Info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27366164/5381354)

> W/Ads﹕ Not enough space to show ad. Needs 320x50 dp, but only has 288x420 dp.

[answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21870253/5427083)